# SQL Query Count With JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following SQL Query which runs perfectly fine but now i want to calculate the count based on the following scenario:

```
      SELECT d.vseverity, v.vulnstatus, v.vtitleid, d.vtitle 
    FROM vulnsummary v 
    JOIN project p ON v.projid = p.projid 
               AND v.stagename = p.currentstage 
    JOIN datasets d ON v.vtitleid = d.datasetid
```

The current Output is:

[image: Text]

Now i want to show the count like this way:

High (Open) - 2

High (Closed) - 0

Medium (Open) - 1

Medium (Closed) - 0

Low (Open) - 3

Low (Closed) - 1

Please help me to solve this query, Thank You

Comment: ' i want to show the count like this way:' - as in one row for each?

Comment: Yes one row for each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `CROSS JOIN` the distinct sets of severity and status values and then `LEFT JOIN` that to your table to allow you to count the values of each severity/status combination. Without sample data it's hard to be certain but something like this should work:

```
SELECT sv.vseverity, st.vulnstatus, COUNT(v.vseverity) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT vseverity
    FROM datasets
) sv
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT vulnstatus
    FROM vulnsummary
) st
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT d.vseverity, v.vulnstatus 
    FROM vulnsummary v 
    JOIN project p ON v.projid = p.projid 
                  AND v.stagename = p.currentstage 
    JOIN datasets d ON v.vtitleid = d.datasetid
) v ON v.vseverity = sv.vseverity AND v.vulnstatus = st.vulnstatus
GROUP BY sv.vseverity, st.vulnstatus
```

Comment: Thank you for the query, but it shows wrong stats actually

Comment: @ChetanSoni as I said: "Without sample data it's hard to be certain". If you could provide some sample data for the `vulnsummary` and `datasets` tables in your question I'm sure it would be a relatively simple fix.

Comment: The join to `project` is missing. Also COUNT(*) should be `COUNT(v.vtitleid)`

Comment: Here is the sample data of vulnsummary table - https://i.imgur.com/UnkDWw1.jpg and here is the sample data of datasets table - https://i.imgur.com/shMVA6y.jpg

Comment: @forpas `project` seems unnecessary for the subquery, no values in it are used. Good point about the `COUNT` though

Comment: I don't know if `project` is needed. Maybe that join filters out rows.

Comment: Here i uploaded the SQL file for both tables - https://safenote.co/r/5ea69f6bf1a4a3@62789984

Comment: @ChetanSoni "Sorry! We are unable to serve with this link because this link has already expired."

Comment: Actually now i got it, you didn't add v.stagename = p.currentstage  because i'm comparing one value from project table too

Comment: @ChetanSoni ah it didn't occur to me that that could filter results. I've edited the query, does that work as expected?

Comment: @forpas oops. you were indeed correct, the `project` table does filter out rows

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your full dataset, however, a RIGHT OUTER JOIN to a master volnstatus table will enable (the volnstatus table showing all options i.e. 'Open', 'Closed'). A rough draft example, with only the volnstatus table populated:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.vulnstatus) CountOf, t.vtype
FROM dbo.vusummary s
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        vusummarytype t
            ON s.vulnstatus = t.vtype
GROUP BY t.vtype
```